# SSIS Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I have the following SQL code

```
update ETL.TempRH 
set resourcer = IF(
               qualification IN (47,49,50,164,187,252,185,239,251),
                   "resourcer"  , type_Staff);
```

and I need to convert it to an ssis expression. I tried this but it didn't work.

```
(qualification = 47  || 
 qualification = 49  ||  
 qualification = 50  || 
 qualification = 164 || 
 qualification = 187 || 
 qualification = 252 || 
 qualification = 185 || 
 qualification = 239 || 
 qualification = 251 ? "resourcer" : type_Staff)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem you have is the equality comparison operator in SSIS is `==` not `=`.

More generally, will those qualifications numbers ever change? Are they even vaguely dynamic?

You might just want to use a Lookup component to store your resourcer qualification values, lookup the qualification value against it, and replace your type_Staff column with "resourcer" if it matches.

So for example in your lookup set the query as

```
SELECT 47 as Qualification, 1 as IsResourcer
union
SELECT 49, 1
etc
etc
```

Join on Qualification, and then in your Derived Column simply do

```
(IsResourcer == 1 ? "Resourcer" : Type_Staff)
```

If you don't care about retaining your original type_Staff value, you could change the lookup query to

```
   SELECT 47 as Qualification, 'Resourcer' as type_Staff
    union
    SELECT 49, 'Resourcer'
    etc
    etc
```

And set type_Staff to replace your existing type_Staff column.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the below Nested Query logic in SSIS expression:

```
Field == "TrueCondition1" ? “True” : ( Field == "TrueCondition2" ? “True” : ( Field == "TrueCondition3 " ? “True” : ( Field == "TrueCondition4" ? “True” : “False"  ) ) )
```

so as per your query Field == qualification & what values you are checking for qualification will become "TrueCondition"

```
@[User::qualification]  == 47 ? @[User::resourcer]  : (@[User::qualification] == 49 ? @[User::resourcer] : (@[User::qualification] == 40 ? @[User::resourcer] : @[User::type_staff] ))
```

Try this.